# Keeping select box size fix on adding options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a city-selector select option like:
[image]

And when I select multiple cities the size of the selector increases like this:
[image]

I want to keep the size fix of the box. Any solution?

Comment: Without knowing the specific JS framework you are using or some sample code, it would be difficult to see alternatives. But for starters you can add an `overflow-y=auto` and `max-height` to get a scrollbar when there are too many options selected.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand, it's that you want. A force maximal width and height with any change.

```css
.select {
  /** Want to have permanant width 150px **/
  width:150px;
  max-width:150px;
  background:lightblue;
  padding:3px;
  height:150px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  /** the magic think **/
  word-break:break-word;
}

.option {
  background:tomato;
  width:100%; /** or display block in your case (for the tags selected) **/
}

.option:nth-child(odd) {
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testtttttttttttttttesttttttttttttttttesttttttttttttttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttttttttttttttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
  <div class="option">testttt</div>
</div>
```